# OpenGl library dont work

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu

i have a problem with the opengl library (glut).
i install this 2:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```

and when i write :

```
g++ -lGL -lglut test1.cpp -o test
```

i have this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-        gnu/libGL.so: No such file or directory
/tmp/cc0332Hc.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/tmp/cc0332Hc.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/tmp/cc0332Hc.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glFlush' 
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 0
```

i use the last version of Elementary Os and gcc compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLUT is *not* "the" OpenGL library. Quite the contrary. It is just some utility library for openGL.

It seems like you don't have a OpenGL implementation installed, which are typically part of the graphics drivers or the OS itself. On Linux, there are the proprietary drivers from NVIDIA and AMD, and the Open Source ones which are developed in the [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org) project. Which one is the best for you depends on the GPU you are using.

Comment: for many distros the package is either "libgl1-mesa-dev" or the GPU driver

Comment: hi thanks for help, im working to install, so i have the privative driver for my graphic card ATI raden hd 5500 , i need to uninstall this to install Mesa?

Comment: the proprietary ATI driver does include a opengl implementation. No need to switch to mesa then (although mesa also should have some open source driver for that GPU). And yes, you can install either one ore the other.

Comment: Thank you,u helped me a lot :D ,and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The library linkage order specified on the command line is significant.  In this case, libglut.so has a dependency on libGL.so, so the command line should have -lglut BEFORE -lGL.  Like so:

```
g++ test1.cpp -lglut -lGL -o test
```

Comment: Good point, but I think ld would not report "[...]/libGL.so: No such file or directory" if it were just the wrong order.

Comment: Ty for the help ! :D. But i have the same error with ur command line.
    g++ test1.cpp -lglut -lGL -o test
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: No such file or directory
/tmp/ccSowmNR.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/tmp/ccSowmNR.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/tmp/ccSowmNR.o:test1.cpp:function draw(): error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sorry--I didn't see the end of the first line of the error message originally.  In that case, @derhass is headed in the right direction I believe.